# Visual Basic - Making a cap on my highscore on my game

Tags: vb.net

I'm a student and I'm on my way to deliver my examproject in Programming on level C.

I'm in the very end of my project, I have programmed a game with a highscore. The highscore saves the score in notepad so it can read the old highscore again when the game is relaunched.

The problem is, everytime a new highscore comes it keep adding a new one. So if I have played 100 games there is 100 highscores and I don't want that. I want to set a limit on my highscore. I'm thinking about 15.

I have two ideas. the first idea is that the program only read the first 15 highscores. 
The second idea is that I create a sub that reads the old highscorelist, then compare it with the new highscore and checks if the old highscorelist needs to be updated.

But the problem is, I'm having a big trouble programming that.. I'll now upload my highscore subs, and ask you for help.

**This is where I write my highscorelist**

```
Private Sub skrivhighscore()
    ReDim Preserve HighscoreNavn(UBound(HighscoreNavn) + 1)
    ReDim Preserve HighscoreLevel(UBound(HighscoreLevel) + 1)

'insets the new highscore on the right place so that level is on top
        For i As Integer = 1 To UBound(HighscoreLevel)
        If (level > HighscoreLevel(i)) Then
            'the new highscore is bigger than highscorecount(i). inset the new here but first move the others 
            For j As Integer = UBound(HighscoreLevel) To i + 1 Step -1
                'kopier array(j-1) til array(j)
                HighscoreNavn(j) = HighscoreNavn(j - 1)
                HighscoreLevel(j) = HighscoreLevel(j - 1)
            Next j
            HighscoreNavn(i) = brugernavn
            ' sets highscore name to username. brugernavn = username
            HighscoreLevel(i) = level
            'set shighscorelvel(I) to the level the user died on.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'clear username and change level to 0
    brugernavn = ""
    level = 0

    'writes highscore to a file so it can be read next time
    highscoreboardskriv()

End Sub
```

**This is where I save my highscorelist to notepad**

```
 Private Sub highscoreboardskriv()
    ' create a file at the same place as the game 
    'append:=False means overwrite and not repleace

    fileWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("HighScore.txt", append:=False)
    For i As Integer = 1 To UBound(HighscoreLevel)
        ' In every line the name is on the first   20 spaces and the score is from space   22
        'example: "Player1            :   2"
        If (HighscoreNavn(i) IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (HighscoreNavn(i).Trim <> "") Then
            ' If username is empty, it will not be written in the highscorelist. by using this method a highscore can be removed. 
            FileLine = HighscoreNavn(i).PadRight(20) & ":" & HighscoreLevel(i).ToString.PadLeft(5)
            fileWriter.WriteLine(FileLine)
        End If
    Next i

    fileWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

**This is where I show my highscorelist**

```
Private Sub Highscore()
    'Now we read both information again from the file 

    Dim HighScoreText As String = ""

    'highscorelist line by line
    For i As Integer = 1 To UBound(HighscoreLevel)
        'takes every spaces in an array (we dont use the first line)
        If (HighscoreNavn(i) IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (HighscoreNavn(i).Trim <> "") Then
            If (HighScoreText <> "") Then
                'new line by every highscore except the first line
                HighScoreText = HighScoreText & vbNewLine
            End If
            'line 1 example: "player1            :   230"
            HighScoreText = HighScoreText & HighscoreNavn(i).PadRight(20) & ":" & HighscoreLevel(i).ToString.PadLeft(5)
        End If
    Next i

    'show highscorelist to user
    MsgBox(HighScoreText, Title:="Highscore list")

End Sub
```

**This is where I read my highscorelist from notepad :**

```
Public Sub highscoreboardlæs()

Public HighscoreNavn(0) As String
Public HighscoreLevel(0) As Integer
Public level As Integer = 0
Public fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
Public FileLine As String

    Try
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("HighScore.txt")

        FileLine = fileReader.ReadLine()

        While (FileLine <> "") 'loop så længe der er linjer i filen, for at få alle highscores med

            'extend array with 1 extra line

            ReDim Preserve HighscoreNavn(UBound(HighscoreNavn) + 1)
            ReDim Preserve HighscoreLevel(UBound(HighscoreLevel) + 1)


            HighscoreNavn(UBound(HighscoreNavn)) = Mid(FileLine, 1, 20)
            HighscoreLevel(UBound(HighscoreLevel)) = Val(Mid(FileLine, 22, 5))

            'read next line from the file
            FileLine = fileReader.ReadLine()
        End While

        fileReader.Close()
    Catch
        'i use try method, else it will crash if there arent any highscorelist
    End Try
    'MsgBox("Highscore: " & vbNewLine & fileReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine & fileReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine & fileReader.ReadLine())
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you translate your code comments to english please...

Comment: To be fair I think the comments in bold above each code snippet provide adequate information

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep 15 scores in the file you could just read all the scores into a array, sort it and write the 15 highest back into the file.
I would not recommend doing that if you have longer score lists, as you load all the scores into the memory, which might give you an OOM (Out Of Memory) exception with bigger lists, but in your case it's completely fine.

```
Sub AddScore(score%, filePath$)
    Dim Scores As New List(Of Integer)

    ' Loads all the scores into our list
    Using Sr As New IO.StreamReader(filePath)
        Do Until Sr.EndOfStream
            Scores.Add(Sr.ReadLine)
        Loop
    End Using

    Scores.Sort() ' Sort it
    Scores.Reverse() ' Reverse it, as the the highest scores is at the bottom. You would property want to just read trough the last 15 items in the list rather than reversing it, but I'm just being lazy.

    ' Write the first 15
    Using Sw As New IO.StreamWriter(filePath, False)
        For i = 0 To Math.Min(Scores.Count - 1, 14)
            Sw.WriteLine(Scores(i))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Oh, and btw, your Swedish right? Would you mind sending me a PM, as I'm quite interested in how programming school is in Sweden.

Comment: Hi, im new to this site, a friend recommended it :) ill try that piece of code right away, thank you :) 
Btw, im from Denmark, i havnt managed to find out how you pm somebody.. ill try google that.. lol

Comment: I translated my comments to english, sry for not doing that earlier..

Im having problem with using your code BlackCap, im not sure how i link to that sub. score% would that be HighscoreLevel(i) and filepath$ would be the path to my game ? once again, thank you

Comment: @Slebo - I don't think SO has a PM feature.  You could exchange e-mail addresses in the comments.  If you don't want your e-mail permanently displayed, simply delete the comment once the other party confirms they have it. And by the way, for your first question on SO you did a great job of writing it and giving both what you had done and what you were trying to do.  Best of luck in school to you :)

Comment: Thank you sir :) 

I have a deadline in 12 hours, so im doing what i can to figure it out ;)

Comment: "Score" is the score you want to add, "filePath" is the path of your highscore file.

% is short for "As Integer"
$ is short for "As String".

Feel free to add me at Skype, it is somewhat faster than writing comments here. Skype: "BlackCapCoder"

Comment: There are no PMs here. That defeats the whole point. Keeping the information public allows it to help others in the future.